# Facebook API: How to delete all users from an event

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I need some help with a small app I'm trying to realize.

I want to make an facebook app with which it's possible to delete all users from an event that have declined attending to it.

My first attempt was as follows:

```
foreach ($declinedUsers as $id) {
    $facebook->api('/'.$_GET['id'].'/invited/'.$id,'DELETE');
}
```

Where **$_GET['id']** is the event id and **$id** the user id.

The problem (of course) is that this is sending one request for each user to facebook. In a case of 1000 or 10000 users that have to be deleted it's taking very long and I don't know if facebook wouldn't block that procedure.

So I'm asking you if there is a way where I can pass multiple user ids to facebook or a way with FQL for example? Do you have any ideas?

I searched a lot over the entire internet but haven't found a solution yet so I hope you can help me.

Thank you very much!